# Capture group stored as variable, Substitution operator returns it as blank?

Tags: perl

```
#!/approot/opt/bin/perl
use strict;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
open FILE, $file or die;
my $line;

while (<FILE>) {

if (m/create unique clustered index \S+ on \S+ \(([^\)]+)\)/) {
  $line = $1;
  }
s/chargeable_items/$line/;

print;
}
```

Here is the text file I am trying to make this work with but everytime it attempts to replace it. It replaces the string with a blank.

```
CREATE TABLE  t_test                                                                                                                         
 (
system_name        varchar(20) NOT NULL,
server_type        smallint NOT NULL,
chargeable_system  bit NOT NULL,
chargeable_items   bit NOT NULL
 )
create unique clustered index host_idx on dbo.t_host (system_name, server_type, environment)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
create nonclustered index tt_host on dbo.t_host (N.A.)
```

Everytime it does the substitution operator it replaces "chargeable_items" with a blank value as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE  t_test                                                                                                                         
 (
system_name        varchar(20) NOT NULL,
server_type        smallint NOT NULL,
chargeable_system  bit NOT NULL,
   bit NOT NULL
 )
create unique clustered index host_idx on dbo.t_host (system_name, server_type, environment)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
create nonclustered index tt_host on dbo.t_host (N.A.)
```

Comment: Tip: `while (<>)` will read from the file(s) passed as arguments, so you didn't need to `open FILE`.

Comment: @Gary I added working example to my answer.

Comment: @Thanks markus I took a looked at what you did and man seems a lot more efficient then the route I took. I decided to read the lines from the file and store it within in array. Then read from the array to find what I need store it within a variable then read from the array again to substitute what I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading file line-by-line in `while` loop.

At line

```
chargeable_items   bit NOT NULL
```

you have not yet set `$line` to any value, so `chargeable_items` is replaced with empty value. You only set `$line` later on line

```
create unique clustered index host_idx on dbo.t_host (system_name, server_type, environment)
```

but `$line` is never used after that since there is no `chargeable_items` after that line.

Working solution would be to read whole file at once and then do matching and substitution:

```
#!/approot/opt/bin/perl
use strict;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
open FILE, $file or die;
local $/;
my $data = <FILE>;

if ($data =~ m/create unique clustered index \S+ on \S+ \(([^\)]+)\)/) {
  my $line = $1;
  $data =~ s/chargeable_items/$line/;
}

print $data;
```

Here `local $/` sets special variable `$/` (input record separator) to undefined value locally, so that `<FILE>` will read whole file at once, instead of line-by-line, which is normal behaviour.